# Vertx - Closing connections - JDBC and others

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have a verticle, which consumes a message from the event bus and processes it. I have a question as to when the JDBC connection should be closed. There are 2 approaches

1. Closing the connection once the message is processed. But this will be very expensive because I will open/close connection every time.
2. Trust that vertx will close the connection when the verticle is stopped/undeployed (which is literally never) and that there wont be any memory leaks as long as the connection is open. I will open the connection in the start() method, so that whenever there is a message it available.

On the other hand, If I have an elastic search backend and I am using the elastic search SDK, which has a specific method to close the client, when should the connection be really closed?

Answer (score 1):

Use a connection pool, that will take away most of the cost of closing/opening connections. When using a connection pool, closing the connection returns it to the connection pool for re-use.

The basic usage pattern is:

```java
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
  // use connection
}
```

At the end of the block the connection is closed, which - if `dataSource` has a connection pool - will make it available for re-use.

Comment: Wouldnt createSharedDatasource automatically create a data source. SQLClient client = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config);

Comment: I don't know Vert.x, so I'm answering from the general JDBC perspective. If that data source created by `createSharedDatasource` provides a connection pool, then your set, and you should close connections at the end of each unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put your *clean up* code in Stop() method of `Verticle` interface. It will be called when the verticle starts it's un-deploy procedure.

See [Vert.x Docs](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/AbstractVerticle.html#start--)

Comment: hi - My question really was if I could leave the connection open until the stop() method without any memory leaks. Also I cant think of when I will be using the stop() method at all..